# Move items between tabs in Oracle forms

Tags: forms, oracle, tabs, textinput

I Have An Oracle tabbed form in 6i and I have a text item on first tab I want to set a code that when I change tab then item should move to the current tab.  I mean the Item should move or viewed only current active tab that when if item is on 1st tab and I select 2nd tab then item on first tab should be placed on 2nd tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think, You cannot move items between tabs, but i needed something like this. It is actually nice to see from tab label, what types of data is currentlly presented and not use buttons or text labels.
If you dont want to create multiple blocks, but only change where clause or change other properties,

1. Take your Item for example BLOCK_A.NAME(on TAB1), duplicate item as 
   BLOCK_A.NAME_2
2. Use *synchronize with item* Property on duplicated    item and choose NAME item from the list.
3. Set TAB You want to display    duplicated item on.

WHEN-TAB-PAGE-CHANGED trigger can look like this:

```
declare
   curr_tab varchar2(30);
begin
    if :SYSTEM.CURRENT_BLOCK in ('BLOCK_A') then
        curr_tab := get_canvas_property('MYTABPAGE',topmost_tab_page); 
        if curr_tab = 'TAB1' then
            --Set WHERE 1, execute_query;
            go_item('BLOCK_A.NAME');--Navigate to TAB1
        else
            --Set WHERE 2, execute_query;
            go_item('BLOCK_A.NAME_2');--Navigate to TABX
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

This way i can have several items with the same datasource, but different properties. 
For direct navigation, just go to apropriate item to show TAB you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trigger "WHEN-TAB-PAGE-CHANGED' that might help you out, but...

...it kind of sounds to me like you want a tabbed canvas on top of another "base" canvas. If you put this field you want always displayed on the base canvas, it's always visible and you don't have to mess with moving data between tabs.

Comment: Is there any way to change the tab for text item on runtime ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Why do you need to do this? Seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

Comment: Actualy i want to make this functionality for tabs coz i dnt want to place item outside of tab from other items due to design purposes and i want to use the one item for all tabs so kindly tell me how can i assign the tab to text item on runtime

Comment: You can't. Look at the item properties available to set on SET_ITEM_PROPERTY built-in, I don't think you'll find tab page as one of them.

Comment: If you must have a field on each tab, then create a field on each tab, and when the tab changes, copy the data to each field.

Comment: How can this possible please elloborate of copying data then i will accept ur answer